# fileno() and files larger than 2gb

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I am working with huge files. (>>>2gb). the question I have is it safe to use fileno() on the file descriptor if the file is larger than sizeof(int) is?

Here a quick code snippet:

```
#define  _FILE_OFFSET_BITS  64
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>


int readstuff(FILE *fp,uint64_t seekpoint, uint64_t seekwidth) {
    int j;
    char buf[seekwidth];

    if (pread(fileno(fp),buf,seekwidth,seekpoint)!=-1) {
        /* do stuf */
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 2;
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE *FP;

    FP=fopen("/testfile","r");
    readstuff(FP,0,10000);
}
```

Comment: `fileno(3)` returns the integer file descriptor associated with the given `FILE` pointer.  Unless you have more than `MAXINT` files open you wont have a problem (and this is unlikely).  Maybe you're thinking of `ftell(3)` which returns a `long`?

Comment: no I was thinking because I don't really know how fileno() works in the background. I thought maybe files larger than 2gb could cause problems since there more than sizeof(int) bytes in the entire file at least on 32bit systems

Comment: I edited the original question to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`fileno(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html) gives a [file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) -which is a fixed small integer once you `fopen`-ed a *stdio* `FILE` stream. A process usually has only dozens of file descriptors, and occasionally (for some servers, see [C10K problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem)) a few dozen of thousands of them.

The kernel is allocating file descriptors (with e.g. [`open(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) etc...), and gives "small" (generally contiguous) integers

Typically, a file descriptor is a non-negative integer often less than 100, and generally less than 100000. Of course the file descriptor is unrelated to the file size.

Try `ls /proc/self/fd/` to list the file descriptors of the process running that `ls` command and `ls /proc/1234/fd/` to list the file descriptors of process of pid 1234.

The command `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` gives the total cumulated maximum number of file descriptors on your system (on mine, it is 1629935 now), and each process has a fraction of that.

You may limit the number of file descriptors a process (and its children) can have with [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) using `RLIMIT_NOFILE`. The `bash` builtin `ulimit` calls that syscall (on my system, the descriptors limit is 1024 by default).

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Comment: thank you this is what I was looking for. I was a little worried fileno() must be as big or smaller as the size of the opened the case. However this isn't the case, as the size is completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

The file descriptor returned by `fileno()` is an `int`, regardless of the size of the file that it is used to open.

Comment: ok so I can safely pread from it? even though I opened with fopen()?

Comment: Yes; you can use `pread()` or `read()` or `readv()` or any other appropriate function that uses a file descriptor for accessing a file.  (That means you can't use functions for a socket.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The value of a file descriptor is unrelated to the size of that file.